# How to increment counter column through Cassandra python-driver ORM

Tags: python, orm, cassandra, counter, cqlengine

I`m using this [python driver](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/object_mapper.html).  How can i increment counter using ORM in correct way?

Maybe smth like `update(counter_value__add=1)` or `obj.counter_value += 1`?

I try to avoid this manual query `UPDATE ... SET counter_value = counter_value + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resolved issue](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-333) which tell, that correct way is `obj.counter_value += 1` But its deprecated!

**Right way is:**

```
CounterModel(pk=pk, ck=ck).update(counter_field=1, another_counter=-2)
```

Also you can use update method of counter model object.

P.S.

- There is no need to create counters, They are `0` by default.
- You cant create counter row via `.create()` method.
- You cant set any value to counter directly.